# How to get negative values from sequencial file csv format? datastage

Tags: transform, datastage

Am taking information from a csv file, one of the columns have negative values, when I get the information in datastage and insert into a table in teradata the negative values dont have the negative simbol like a negative, instead appear a dash. For this reason at the moment to cast to decimal is not possible.

Comment: Which data type have you defined reading the csv for that column? Try decimal there so it get interpreted right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try selecting the field type as varchar in the .csv stage. This will generate an warning but the value will be pulled in. Later you can do necessary conversion. 
Or you can see if in your unix environment you can convert that file to sequential file.